# How can I set the UTF-8 encoding in my php contact form. Only latin characters show up correctly

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

This is the php code of the contact form of my website. The thing is that there isn't any utf-8 encoding so the characters (besides latin) return as symbols .
The data are inserted in an array, so the array returns as info.

```
function handle_form_postdata( $post_array ) {
    $data = array();

    // Sanitize data, or initialize if they don't exist.
    $data['the_name']    = isset( $post_array['the_name'] ) ? trim( $post_array['the_name'] ) : '';
    $data['the_email']   = isset( $post_array['the_email'] ) ? trim( $post_array['the_email'] ) : '';
    $data['arrive']      = isset( $post_array['arrive'] ) ? trim( $post_array['arrive'] ) : '';
    $data['depart']      = isset( $post_array['depart'] ) ? trim( $post_array['depart'] ) : '';
    $data['guests']      = isset( $post_array['guests'] ) ? trim( $post_array['guests'] ) : '';
    $data['room_select']      = isset( $post_array['room_select'] ) ? trim( $post_array['room_select'] ) : '';
    $data['children']    = isset( $post_array['children'] ) ? trim( $post_array['children'] ) : '';
    $data['the_message'] = isset( $post_array['the_message'] ) ? filter_var( $post_array['the_message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) : '';
    $data['errorString'] = '';
    $data['emailbody']   = '';
    $data['emailSent']   = false;

            $data['emailSent'] = mail( 'info@alleywayhouse-hydra.gr', 'Availability question for alleywayhouse-hydra', $data['emailbody'], 'From: "' . $data['the_name'] . '" <' . $data['the_email'] . '>' );  
        }
    }

    return $data;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail function requires:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)
```

Add header to the fourth param in function

```
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

It should looks like this:

```
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n".
           "From: {$data['the_name']} <{$data['the_email']}>";
$subject = 'Availability question for alleywayhouse-hydra';

$data['emailSent'] = mail('info@alleywayhouse-hydra.gr', $subject, $data['emailbody'], $headers);
```

Also, your function can be refactored like this:

```
function handle_form_postdata($post_array)
{
    $data = [];
    $keys = ['the_name', 'the_email', 'arrive', 'depart', 'guests', 'room_select', 'children'];

    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $data[$key] = isset($post_array[$key]) ? trim($post_array[$key]) : '';
    }

    $data['the_message'] = isset($post_array['the_message']) ? filter_var($post_array['the_message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';
    $data['errorString'] = '';
    $data['emailbody'] = '';
    $data['emailSent'] = false;

    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n" .
        "From: {$data['the_name']} <{$data['the_email']}>";
    $subject = 'Availability question for alleywayhouse-hydra';

    $data['emailSent'] = mail('info@alleywayhouse-hydra.gr', $subject, $data['emailbody'], $headers);

    return $data;
}
```